# HashLocationStrategy not working in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 7 application and I want to use HashLocationStrategy. In `app.module.ts` I tried both versions `RouterModule.forRoot(appMainRoutes, { useHash: true })` and `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }`, but I got the same error after login

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'state'

This is the `app.routes.ts`

```
export const appMainRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ROUTE.default,
        component: WelcomePageComponent,
        canActivate: [CookiesGuard]
    },
    {
        path: ROUTE.empty,
        component: WelcomePageComponent,
        canActivate: [CookiesGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'subscriptions',
        component: SubscriptionsPageComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, CookiesGuard]
    },
];
```

Comment: Can you add your routing file.

Comment: I edited the question. The welcome page contains the login button and if the user is logged in, I navigate to subscriptions page. If I remove the useHash, then everything works fine.